# show/Hide Ribbon command in Officejs

Tags: office-js, ribbonx

Wanted to show/hide custom ribbon button using officejs in typescript.

Tried getting element of custom ribbon button using jquery but not able to get the same since id getting random every time excel run.

$("#id__1157").id.hide()

Expected Result: Wanted to show/hide custom ribbon button in Excel using officejs in typescript

Answer (score 5):

The ability to how/hide a custom ribbon button is not yet available in the Office JavaScript library. But we are working on it and hope to have it soon.

UPDATE May, 2021: Custom contextual tabs is now available on Excel. For details, see [Create custom contextual tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/contextual-tabs)

Comment: Hi Rick, Any progress on this feature? Also please find below requirement.                                      1) Login button should be in ribbon command,                                                            2) once login successful, login button should be replaced with xsi:type="Menu" control.                                                                                                                                  Can you please confirm ASAP.

Comment: Can you please confirm as I can see preview in official website. But  I tried  below    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>getSubject</FunctionName>
  </Action>
  <Enabled>false</Enabled>
</Control>

Comment: This is still not available. We are previewing a feature in Excel only that will allow add-ins to programmatically enable and disable ribbon buttons, but the feature will not allow them to hide or show buttons.

Comment: We have a "no vaporware" policy at Microsoft, so I have to be hazy, but I can tell you we are working on a show/hide feature.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Rick... And looking forward with feature ASAP...

Comment: Is this available for Word?

Comment: @PeterDongan Nope. Only available with Excel.

Comment: @RickKirkham ok thanks